# Creating an object with a different reference type and instance type

Tags: java, interface

How can I improve the program implementation? The program failed when tested with reference type as the interface and instance type as the implementation classes . Concentrate on creating an object with a different reference type and instance type.

```
package com;
interface Shape {
public abstract double getArea(double d);
}
public class TestCircle {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Circle s = new Circle();
    System.out.println(s.getArea(5));
    System.out.println(calculateArea(s,5));
    Shape s1 = new Square();
    System.out.println(calculateArea(s1,5));
}
public static double calculateArea(Shape s, double d){
    if(s==null) return 0.0;
    return s.getArea(d);
}
}
class Circle implements Shape{
public double getArea(double d){
    if(d<0) return 0.0;
    return d*d*(22.0/7);
}
}
class Square implements Shape{
public double getArea(double d){
    //if(d<0)   return 0.0;
    return d*d;
}
}
```

Comment: In what way did the program fail?

Comment: "The program failed" ? What was the failure?  May be you'd want: `final Shape s = new Circle();`

Comment: "Creating an object with a different reference type and instance type" is gibberish. It should be "declare a variable with a given type and initialize it with an instance of a subtype". (I realize that you just copied-and-pasted from your homework, so it's not really your fault, but still . . .)

Comment: Am I the only one who is not able to decrypt the question ? ...:P

Comment: programming is running smoothly but I wanted to know if anyway I could improve the program

Comment: where it fails ?? can you clarify, because i don't think so!!!!! what you want to improve?

Answer (score -1):

Re-factored your code a little. Elaborate what are you trying to achieve. You may not need static calculateArea()!

```
package com;
interface Shape {
    public double getArea(double d);
}
public class TestCircle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = new Circle();
        System.out.println(s.getArea(5d));
        System.out.println(calculateArea(s,5d));
        Shape s1 = new Square();
        System.out.println(calculateArea(s1,5d));
    }
    public static double calculateArea(Shape s, double d){
        if(s==null) return 0d;
        return s.getArea(d);
    }
}
class Circle implements Shape{
    public double getArea(double d){
        if(d<0) return 0d;
        return d*d*(22.0/7);
    }
}
class Square implements Shape{
    public double getArea(double d){
        //if(d<0)   return 0.0;
        return d*d;
    }
}
```